# How to remove words containing only numbers in python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have some text in Python which is composed of numbers and alphabets. Something like this:

```
s = "12 word word2"
```

From the string s, I want to remove all the words containing **only numbers**

So I want the result to be

```
s = "word word2"
```

This is a regex I have but it works on alphabets i.e. it replaces each alphabet by a space.

```
re.sub('[\ 0-9\ ]+', ' ', line)
```

Can someone help in telling me what is wrong? Also, is there a more time-efficient way to do this than regex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
>>> s = "12 word word2"
>>> print re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+\b\s*', '', s)
word word2
```

`\b` is used for word boundary and `\s*` will remove 0 or more spaces after your number word.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Can the regex be modified to remove all punctuation/special symbols as follows ?
re.sub(r'\b[!~`.,/<>]+\b\s*', '', s)

Comment: Sure you can use: `re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+\b\W*', '', s)` as `\W` matches space or any other non-word character.

Answer (score 7):

Using a regex is probably a bit overkill here depending whether you need to preserve whitespace:

```
s = "12 word word2"
s2 = ' '.join(word for word in s.split() if not word.isdigit())
# 'word word2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any external library you could do:

```
stringToFormat = "12 word word2"
words = ""
for word in stringToFormat.split(" "):
    try:
        int(word)
    except ValueError:
        words += "{} ".format(word)
print(words)
```